# retrofit2/OkHttp3 cancel all API requests

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

After user logout I want to cancel all API calls that are executing right now. So I found a way to do so

```
httpClient.dispatcher().cancelAll();
```

However in the [callback side](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Callback.java#L44) I need to know that this request was canceled to not retry it and not to show error message to user.
 But `call.isCanceled()` will be `true` if only `call.cancel()` was been called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem with moving to `jxJava` 

I save all my `Observable` to `CompositeSubscription`
and after use `compositeSubscription.unsubscribe();` to get rid of all callbacks

Answer (score 0):

`Dispatcher.cancelAll()` just calls `Call.cancel()` for you.

Comment: However to do this I have to store all my executing calls?

Comment: No, you just need to keep a reference to the shared OkHttpClient.